# Error while trying to update the records in the oracle data base - ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to update one db table with the data that has been ingested from the CSV file.

I am getting hit with the following error: **ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables**

The query I use is as follows:

```
merge into mdm_tableau_events_copy t
using mdm_tableau_events_test s
on (t.ID = s.ID)
when matched then update set t.FULL_NAME = s.FULL_NAME, t.PROJECT_NAME = s.PROJECT_NAME, t.EVENTS = s.EVENTS, t.DATE_USE = s.DATE_USE, t.COMPANY = s.COMPANY, t.WORKBOOK = s.WORKBOOK;
```

Comment: Sounds like ID is not unqiue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's no 1:1 relationship between T.ID and S.ID, so Oracle doesn't know which row to take. If that's so, one option is to pick *any* value (e.g. the `MAX` one), but you'll have to *expand* the `using` clause to something like this:

```
merge into mdm_tableau_events_copy t
using (select id,
              max(full_name) full_name,
              max(project_name) project_name
              -- put the rest of columns here, also with MAX
       from mdm_tableau_events_test
       group by id
      ) s
on (t.ID = s.ID)
when matched then update set 
  t.FULL_NAME = s.FULL_NAME, 
  t.PROJECT_NAME = s.PROJECT_NAME, 
  t.EVENTS = s.EVENTS, 
  t.DATE_USE = s.DATE_USE, 
  t.COMPANY = s.COMPANY, 
  t.WORKBOOK = s.WORKBOOK;
```

Comment: That will not update  mdm_tableau_events_copy  with one existing row from mdm_tableau_events_test but with an artificial one built out of the MAX, so the first step should be to understand why you have dups per ID and then decide how to select the right row for the update, maybe this will fit your needs maybe not, and you will need something more complex with a subquery or analytical functions…

Comment: Right, @p3consulting, that's what I said right above code I posted.